# Connecting Microsoft SQL Server Query File with Excel

Tags: excel

I wrote some queries using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio and saved the queries as "Microsoft SQL Server Query File". I now want to obtain the results of these queries in an Excel File.

I am able to obtain the results of queries written in MS Access in an Excel File by clicking on data > other sources > from microsoft query > selecting my MS Access file > selecting my query.

But I am unable to find a similar way to import the results of a query written using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

Any tips for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Excel 
1 - Go to Data Tab .
2- From Other sources .
3 From SQL Server .

It starts a wizard for your SQL server definition.
At the end of wizard On the Import Data form Click properties.
Goto Defenition tab.
Chnage Commans Type from table to SQL and paste your SQL there